# how to set the value from controller to Visual force page

Tags: visualforce

Can any one help me ?How to set the value from controller to Visual force page?I have a Visualforce page created on Opportunity object which is in PDF format. I have a few RollUp summary fields created on opportunity object. There is a Wrapper class written on Opportunity Product. Now I would like to call these RollUp summary fields in the wrapper class based on a Condition. How do I wrap the RollUp summary field in a class?

"Subtotal__c" and "Non_Pick_Total__c" are Roll up summary fields on Opportunity Object.They give the "Sum" of Opportunity Product aggregates on Extension Field.

Extension(Extension=qty*1) is a Formula field data type as Currency on Opportunity Product.

The issue I'm having is that the "Extension" field value is getting calculated based on the formula field but it should get calculated as per the changes made in the visual force page and display (Extension = Qty*0.01) on the subtotal.

Any help very much appreciated.

Based on the Conditions the value need to get changed in the VF page.

1)When the Product line = "DIE"

Unit price=0.01 **// Condition Works**

Extension = Qty*0.01 **// Condition Works**

**Subtotal = Non_Pick_Total__c; // Now it should display the value of extension based on the logic written ,but it displays the value from the database.**

2)When the Product line != "DIE"

Unit price=1 // Condition Works

Extension = Qty*1 // Condition Works

Subtotal = Non_Pick_Total__c; // Condition Works

Code :

```
 if(OPplineitem[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c=='DIE') 
                     {
                      tempObj.unitprice=0.01;
                      tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Quantity * tempObj.unitprice;
                      tempObj.productname=OPplineitem[i].Bin_Item_Code__c;
                      //tempObj.Subtotal =j;
                      if(i==0){
                      tempObj2.Subtotal=tempobj.extension;
                     }
                     else{
                      tempObj2.Subtotal=tempObj2.Subtotal+tempObj.extension;
                       }

                    // tempObj1.Subtotal =tempObj1.Subtotal+tempObj.extension;
                     system.debug('@@@@@@@@'+tempObj2.Subtotal);

                    //tempObj.NonPickTotal=OPplineitem[i].Opportunity.Non_Pick_Total__c*tempObj.unitprice;

                     }
                 else
                     {
                     tempObj.unitprice=1;
                     //tempObj.unitprice=OPplineitem[i].ListPrice;
                     tempobj.extension=OPplineitem[i].Extension__c ;
                    }
```

PFA ScreenShot
[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? Can you edit your question to clarify your problem?

Comment: @Mark Pond:I have updated the question with the code and Screenshot.

Comment: @Mark Pond:The issue I'm having is that the "Extension" field value is getting calculated based on the formula field but it should get calculated as per  logic written and change the  value in the visual force page and display on the subtotal.IN Screenshot the value of Extensions gets reflected as (4.5,4.0,2.5) and the Subtotal as (1100) but it should get reflected as 11.Any help very much appreciated.